# Need some help about parallel programming using OpenMP?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, multicore

Right now, I am doing parallel programming using OpenMP in Multi core Machine. I am a new in parallel programming.

Till now I have done following thing:

1 million x 1 million Matrix multiplication program using OpenMP

Calculate the execution time with variation the number of thread at different machine (as like corei5, corei3)

I have seen that when no of thread =4, its the minimum time need to execute my code. (I don't know why)

Overall its an performance analysis. Now I want to go gem5. Now what can I do or what is the right way for me? I want to know, what can I do from here. I need an idea.

Answer (score 0):

> I have seen that when no of thread =4, its the minimum time need to
>   execute my code. (i don't know why)

The performance and running times of programs depends on the architecture of the computer. So probably, you can reason it out if you run through your PC's tech specifications. I would guess that it's a *quad-core processor*...

It can also depend on actual control flow, thread creation overheads and similar miscellaneous aspects.

The next steps you might take can be:

- Search for a better algorithm for matrix multiplication which features a lower asymptotic time complexity!
- Improve the current execution time; By identifying hot parts of code using profiling tools like gprof...
- Explore advanced constructs of **openMP** for extracting maximum parallelism out of your code